# REST WebService and concurrency in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, concurrency

I'm going to write a simple REST webservice for downloading files from server( a simple GET method)
The question is: Do I have to handle concurrency in this situation or the web server is going to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "handle concurrency". Do you have to write code to spawn threads on each incoming request? No, Jersey will create a new thread for each request before it calls your API method. Do you need to worry about a `DELETE` request coming in when somebody else is `GET`ing a file? Yup.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, bit of a vague question but:

- Depends on how you implement the REST service, using JAX-RS?
- Depends on the server you are running it on.
- What do you mean by "handle concurrency"? Since REST is stateless, concurrency should be none of your concern.

Comment: I'm using jeresy and tomcat

Comment: Statelessness is a responsibility of the programmer, it is not a guarantee of the technology ;) That would be the true answer: stick to the stateless design philosophy of the standard (REST) and stick to the documentation of the API (JAX-RS) and you needn't worry.

Comment: If it's not stateless, it's not a REST webservice. So assuming we are building a REST webservice we can deduce statelesness.

Answer (score 1):

If yo're using only method-local variables, concurency is not an issue (container handles this).